# How to conditionally add component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code looks to somethis like

```
<iOSOnlyComponent>
.....
.....
.....
</iOSOnlyComponent>
```

Want to use the `iOSOnlyComponent` only on iOS. I tried this

```
{isIOS && <iOSOnlyComponent>}
.....
.....
.....
{isIOS && </iOSOnlyComponent>}
```

But I got a syntax error

Comment: Can you share your `render` method, where you want to conditionally render `iOSOnlyComponent`?

Comment: The render method is huge. I want to use KeyboardAvoidingView only on iOS

Comment: Alright, can you please share the error that you have got?

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like  (untested code)

```
 render() {
    const helloMessageIOS = <iOSOnlyComponent> Hello, JSX! </iOSOnlyComponent>;
  return (
    <ScrollView >
       {isIOS  && helloMessageIOS   }
    </ScrollView >
  );
}
```

If iOSOnlyComponent component is huge, you can simply add it to a function and return it from there.

May be as below (untested code)

```
render() {
    return (
    <View >
       {isIOS  && {this.displayComponent()}   }
    </View >
  );
}


displayComponent() {
   return <iOSOnlyComponent> Hello, JSX! </iOSOnlyComponent>;
}
```

Comment: You can easily split it afaik

Answer (score 1):

If the conditionnal rendering makes your component too complex you can simply separate it in 2 files naming them `myComponent.android.js` and `myComponent.ios.js` then simply `import  myComponent from './myComponent'`

React will choose the right file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional rendering.

```
 renderIosComp(){
    if(isIOS){   //use your variable here ideally props or state should be used
      return(<iOSOnlyComponent>
              .........
             ..........
            <iOSOnlyComponent />);
    }
    else{
         return(<div></div>);
    }
 }
```

call this inside your render method

```
render(){
   return(<div>  
         .......
         ......
          {this.renderIosComp()}
          </div>);
}
```